# Set Server Path for require file in Config?

Tags: php

So i have a Config file setup and i am unable to use a simple ../ etc. I need to be able to use the full server path if possible. the reason being i have multiple pages where i have this included however some are outside the actual main folder that holds classes folder. And since i am requiring i get errors such as Classes/class.php not found. Does this make sense?

here is my Config file might make more sense:

```
<?php
session_start();

$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
'mysql' => array(
    'host' => 'url',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'db' => 'table'
),
'sitekey' => array(
    // DO NOT MODIFY!!
    'uniquekey' => 'Unique Key for Authentication'  
)
);

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once '../classes/' . $class . '.php'; << need to modify!
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [__DIR__](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../classes/' . $class . '.php'; // full path
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a nasty, dirty hack I put together some time ago to assist my co-workers (who are designers and not developers and don't care about nasty, dirty hacks).

```
$depth = substr_count(substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],1),'/');
$path = "";
if ($depth > 0) { for ($i=0;$i < $depth;$i++) { $path .= '../'; } }
```

That will put a sufficient number of "../" to get you back to the domain root. You can then add `$path .= 'subdirectory/';` afterwards to traverse back to the root of your site if it's not at the root itself.

You can then call `$path` wherever you need to have a variable relative path.